# HTML UI for C++ prog

Tags: c++, html, user-interface, mobile, executable

I'm writing a program for mobile in C++, which includes the core, but for the GUI I wanna use HTML.

What I desire to happen is either:

- I open the HTML file from file browser and supposedly server side actions will be done by the binary file alongside the HTML file that is there in the same directory.
- I run the program (either way the mobile platform suggests. Tapping an Icon, etc.) and the HTML GUI pops out **somehow**.

My question is the **"somehow"** in the second case, or (in first case) a method like some JavaScript ability (if ever) that could execute the program given it's **stdin** and receiving it's **stdout**.

The platform that matters is Android.

Edit: And I must mention that I've done this on PC, running apache and running the core executable as CGI, but its not the most straightforward method for a typical PC/mobile user, and I want the supposed mobile user to be able to execute this program just with a tap, send it using OBEX, and so on.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should look into CGI scripting

Comment: Sorry, I was just editing while you commented. Please read my edit too now. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to write an Android app in C++? Use the Java API, it has great integration with HTML. You can even register Java callback methods that can be triggered via Javascript from your HTML.

Comment: My knowledge on Java is epsilon and I never intend to increase it. Still I seek the solution to my problem which I guess should not be out of the 2 methods I mentioned. AND ALSO its not an Android specific app, since only the core is binary, ELF, and GUI is HTML, cross platform.